# Spark saveAsTextFile writes empty file - <directory>_$folder$ to S3

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql

`rdd.saveAsTextFile("s3n://bucket-name/path)` is creating an empty file with folder name as - `[folder-name]_$folder$`
Seems like this empty file in used by `hadoop-aws jar (of org.apache.hadoop)` to mimick S3 filesystem as hadoop filesystem.

But, my application writes thousands of files to S3. As `saveAsTextFile` creates folder (from the given path) to write the data (from rdd) my application ends up creating thousands of these empty files - `[directory-name]_$folder$`.

Is there a way to make `rdd.saveAsTextFile` not to write these empty files?

Answer (score 0):

Stop using s3n, switch to s3a. It's faster and actually supported. that will make this issue go away, along with the atrocious performance problems reading large Parquet/ORC files.

Also, if your app is creating thousands of small files in S3, you are creating future performance problems: listing and opening files on S3 is slow. Try to combine source data into larger columnar-formatted files & use whatever SELECT mechanism your framework has to only read the bits you want

Comment: I tried with `s3a` but still it's creating `<directory-name>_$folder$` files.

Comment: no its not. I say that having just rechecked the source for `S3AFileSystem`, which is in the IDE in front of me. The `$folder$` suffix is looked for on a directory check, but never created. IF they are appearing, then something other than s3a is doing it.

Comment: Can you share me what filesystem implementation you are using? i.e. the value of `fs.s3a.impl`, I'm using `org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem`.

Comment: like I said, you aren't using s3a. You should not have to set any property there, as it will be picked from the base configuration of core-default.xml in hadoop-common.jar. Just use s3a:// URLs

Comment: No, my job asks for `fs.s3a.impl` when I don't provide it. I don't have a way to update `core-default.xml` (on the node I'm deploying my app), so, what property/value does the spark pick from `core-default`.

Comment: Also, I'm trying to run on my local machine too where I don't have `core-defualts.xml`.

Comment: it's core-defaults.xml and its in hadoop-common.jar. you will have it unless whatever is loading the configurations says "don't give me the defaults". A lot of the S3A config (and other bits of hadoop) depend on that file, so it should really be doing that (ie new Configuration() not new Configuration(false))